# Orbeon 4.0 with custom persistence layer

Tags: orbeon

I want to set up my custom persistence layer to work with Orbeon Form Designer 4.0. But I have a problem with the toolbox on the link side of Designer. The toolbox is not shown, if I edit the `properties-local.xml` like this:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*"
          value="myDB"/>
<property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.fr.persistence.myDB.uri"
          value="http://127.0.0.1:8080/my-persistence"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're seeing this this because Orbeon Forms has some trouble talking to your persistence layer. The toolbox shows entries for [section templates](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/user-guide/form-builder-user-guide/section-templates), which usually come from a special published form called `library` in the same app as your current form. So to show section templates, it needs to be able to talk to the persistence layer.

I recommend you check the `orbeon.log` for errors, and use a tool like [Charles](http://blog.orbeon.com/2013/04/let-charles-help-you-monitor-http.html) to monitor the HTTP connections from Orbeon Forms to your own persistence layer.